# npm start - SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word at Loader.moduleStrategy and at async link

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-start

I am new with reactjs and I was trying to open an existing project. I found some solutions and tried them. but I cant get over with this one.
Version details of npm and nodejs are written below npm-cache log.

This error occurs when I try to

> npm start

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\MSBuild\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\NodeJs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\MSBuild\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\NodeJs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.11
3 info using node@v12.20.1
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle @lidojs/source@0.0.0~prestart: @lidojs/source@0.0.0
6 info lifecycle @lidojs/source@0.0.0~start: @lidojs/source@0.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle @lidojs/source@0.0.0~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @lidojs/source@0.0.0~start: PATH: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\NodeJs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\react\canva\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\compiler;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;D:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\NodeJs;C:\Users\MSI GS73 Stealth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\;C:\Users\MSI GS73 Stealth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\;C:\Users\MSI GS73 Stealth\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\MSI GS73 Stealth\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\MSI GS73 Stealth\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;D:\xampp\php;C:\Users\MSI GS73 Stealth\.dotnet\tools;
9 verbose lifecycle @lidojs/source@0.0.0~start: CWD: C:\react\canva
10 silly lifecycle @lidojs/source@0.0.0~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'vite' ]
11 silly lifecycle @lidojs/source@0.0.0~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @lidojs/source@0.0.0~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: @lidojs/source@0.0.0 start: `vite`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\NodeJs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:314:20)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\NodeJs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1022:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:287:5)
14 verbose pkgid @lidojs/source@0.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\react\canva
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19045
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\MSBuild\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\NodeJs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\MSBuild\\Microsoft\\VisualStudio\\NodeJs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v12.20.1
19 verbose npm  v6.14.11
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error @lidojs/source@0.0.0 start: `vite`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the @lidojs/source@0.0.0 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO. Please try to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)